# React Native Large JSON 5MB with AXIOS

Tags: react-native, axios, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I'm trying to import a larger JSON with 5MB up to 8MB into my REALM database in a react native app with AXIOS.

All other calls from same API with less data works fine, but when I try this specific call "linksearch3" that returns this amount data (5MB) I receive the error:

```
> { [Error: Network Error]   config:     { url:
> 'myapi/path/linksearch3?cdColaborador=7442',
>      method: 'get',
>      headers: 
>       { Accept: '*/*',
>         'X-Session-ID': 'my-session-id-1234',
>         'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
>         Connection: 'keep-alive' },
>      baseURL: 'http://myip.com:8080/',
>      transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
>      transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
>      timeout: 0,
>      adapter: [Function: xhrAdapter],
>      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
>      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
>      maxContentLength: Infinity,
>      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
>      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
>      transitional: 
>       { silentJSONParsing: true,
>         forcedJSONParsing: true,
>         clarifyTimeoutError: false },
>      data: undefined },   request:     { UNSENT: 0,
>      OPENED: 1,
>      HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2,
>      LOADING: 3,
>      DONE: 4,
>      readyState: 4,
>      status: 0,
>      timeout: 0,
>      withCredentials: true,
>      upload: {},
>      _aborted: false,
>      _hasError: true,
>      _method: 'GET',
>      _perfKey: 'network_XMLHttpRequest_http://myip.com:8080/myapi/path/linksearch3?cdColaborador=7442',
>      _response: 'unexpected end of stream',
>      _url: 'http://myip.com:8080/myapi/path/linksearch3?cdColaborador=7442',
>      _timedOut: false,
>      _trackingName: 'unknown',
>      _incrementalEvents: false,
>      _performanceLogger: 
>       { _timespans: 
>          { 'network_XMLHttpRequest_http://myip.com:8080/rest-api/auth': 
>             { startTime: 8630575.8016,
>               startExtras: undefined,
>               endExtras: undefined,
>               endTime: 8630951.7208,
>               totalTime: 375.91919999942183 },
>            'network_XMLHttpRequest_http://myip.com:8080/path/linkserach1': 
>             { startTime: 8631528.126,
>               startExtras: undefined,
>               endExtras: undefined,
>               endTime: 8631973.0137,
>               totalTime: 444.8876999989152 },
>            'network_XMLHttpRequest_http://myip.com:8080/path/linksearch2': 
>             { startTime: 8632033.7623,
>               startExtras: undefined,
>               endExtras: undefined,
>               endTime: 8632421.9302,
>               totalTime: 388.16789999976754 },
>            'network_XMLHttpRequest_http://myip.com:8080/path/linksearch3': 
>             { startTime: 8632478.1932,
>               startExtras: undefined,
>               endExtras: undefined,
>               endTime: 8656735.1845,
>               totalTime: 24256.991299999878 },
>            'network_XMLHttpRequest_http://myip.com:8080/path/linksearch4': 
>             { startTime: 8660848.4174,
>               startExtras: undefined,
>               endExtras: undefined,
>               endTime: 8661277.8728,
>               totalTime: 429.455399999395 },
>            'network_XMLHttpRequest_http://myip.com:8080/path/linksearch5': 
>             { startTime: 8661367.8179,
>               startExtras: undefined,
>               endExtras: undefined,
>               endTime: 8662393.9181,
>               totalTime: 1026.1001999992877 },
>            'network_XMLHttpRequest_http://myip.com:8080/myapi/path/linksearch3?cdColaborador=7442':
> { startTime: 8662680.029, startExtras: undefined } },
>         _extras: {},
>         _points: 
>          { initializeCore_start: 64197.2119,
>            initializeCore_end: 64461.4723 },
>         _pointExtras: {},
>         _closed: false },
>      responseHeaders: undefined,
>      _requestId: null,
>      _cachedResponse: undefined,
>      _headers: 
>       { accept: '*/*',
>         'x-session-id': 'my-session-id-1234',
>         'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
>         connection: 'keep-alive' },
>      _responseType: '',
```

With "Postman" I'm able to receive the response normally, it takes about 30 seconds to receive the response.

[image]

My request code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import apiConfig from './apiAuth/config';
import {getAccessToken} from '../services/apiAuth/tokenClient';

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiConfig.baseUrl,
  timeout: 0,
  maxContentLength: Infinity,
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
  },
});

export {apiClient};
```

My Realm import code (works for all other requests):

```
  requestPrices = async (httpClient) => {
    let itens = null;
    await httpClient
      .get(apiConfig.url_prices)
      .then((response) => {
        itens = response.data;
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          if (itens) {
            const databaseOptions = {allSchemas};
            Realm.open(databaseOptions).then((realm) => {
              realm.write(() => {
                if (itens) {
                  const resolveItens = itens.prices.map(async (obj, k) => {
                    console.log('inserting price of item = ', k);
                    return await realm.create('Price', obj, true);
                  });
                  Promise.all(resolveItens).then(() => resolve(true));
                } else {
                  console.log('itens: ', itens);
                }
              });
            });
          } else {
            resolve(true);
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        Alertmsg.danger('Price: ' + Const.SYNC_DATA_ERROR);
      });
```

Please, someone can Help Me!

Comment: What version of Axios are you using?

Comment: "axios": "^0.21.0",